# SwiftでSearchBarを使う

Tags: swift

SwiftでSearchBarに文字を入れて検索する という機能を使いたいのですが

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    
    if let text = searchB.text {
        if text == "" {
            return 
        } else {
            searchArray = searchVC.mainArray.filter { (str) -> Bool in
                return str.contains(text)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

としてもエンターが押せないので

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

というものを探したのですが どう組み合わせればエンターを押したとき検索バーの文字を含むセルをsearchArrayに表示できますか？

Comment: 「エンターが押せない」と言うことですが、デフォルトではソフトウェアキーボードには「search」ボタンが表示されるはずです。それを押したときに検索を行うのではいけないのでしょうか？

Comment: それが出ないのですが…

Comment: 「それが出ない」と言うのは、ソフトウェアキーボードに「search」ボタンが表示されないと言う意味でしょうか？普通なら表示されるものが表示されないのであれば、それはIB上の設定かあなたが示していない部分のコードでおかしなことをやっているせいだと思います。どのようにして`UISearchBar`を画面上に表示しているのか、具体的な手順やコードを示していただけませんか？また、こんな表示になってしまうと言う画面キャプチャーを質問中に貼り付けていただければ何かわかることがあるかもしれません。